# Using same code in Main and AsyncTask gives different results

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, bufferedreader

Im trying to get the progress of a download using the following code:

**Java Program Code:**

```
URLConnection conn = null;
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");
    conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.connect();
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    int fileSize = conn.getContentLength();
    System.out.println("File size " + fileSize);
    int count;
    int i=0;
    while ((count = in.read()) != -1) {
        i++;
        if(i%50000==0){//Prints the decimal percentage every 50000 bytes
            System.out.println(((double)i)/((double)fileSize));
        }
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println("Read " + i + " bytes of a possible " + fileSize);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When i try this same code in the Main of a java application i get the (almost) correct output:

> Read 191202 bytes of a possible 191174

Now if i try and integrate this into the `AsyncTask` of an android app, using the exact same code within the `AsyncTask`s `doInBackground()` and calling the `AsyncTask` in `onCreate()` (shown below) I get the result

> Read 156846 bytes of a possible 16983

So not only is the filesize wrong in android but the number of bytes read in are different too? Im downloading the same file and getting completely different results. I have run both multiple times and both give approximately the same results (stackoverflow does vary very slightly in size but only by about +/-5000 bytes). Can someone explain this and help me fix it?

**Android Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new LoadData().execute();
    }

    private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            URLConnection conn = null;
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");
                conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                int fileSize = conn.getContentLength();
                System.out.println("File size " + fileSize);
                int count;
                int i=0;
                while ((count = in.read()) != -1) {
                    i++;
                    if(i%50000==0){//Prints the decimal percentage every 50000 bytes
                        System.out.println(((double)i)/((double)fileSize));
                    }
                }
                in.close();
                System.out.println("Read " + i + " bytes of a possible " + fileSize);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```